# Convert a string to variable in underscore template using Backbone.js and Marionette,js

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, underscore.js-templating

I have this JSON: 
(looks like bad practice to me but I don't have access to modify it)

```
{
  "content": [{
     "block": {
        "params": "{\u0022slider\u0022:\u00221\u0022}",
        },
   }],
}
```

Then I did this in my underscore.js template:

```
  <% _.each(content, function(item){ %>
    <li> 
        <%=item.block.params %>
    </li>
  <% }); %>
```

It prints a string "{slider:1}" 
How can I convert this string to a variable directly in my template?

If it can't be done , how can this be done from Marionette using CompositeView and ItemView.

here is my code:

```
MarionetteApp.module("WsApp.List", function(List, MarionetteApp, Backbone,   Marionette, $, _) {
 List.Wss = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
   tagName: "div",
   template: "#ws-list-item", 
 });
 List.Ws = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
   tagName: "div",
   className: "item",
   template: "#ws-list",
   childView: List.Wss,
   childViewContainer: ".inner-content",
 });
});
```

Thanks

FIND A SOLUTION:
I have to map the response with backbone , Also works with Marionette Serialized data function 
Thanks Everyone

```
Entities.WsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: function() {

    return "/api.php/posts";
  },
  model: Entities.Ws,
  parse: function(response){
  var items = _.map(response.content, function (item, index) {
   return {
     block: item['block'],
     params:JSON.parse(item['block']['params']),
     };
  });
  return items;
},

});
```

Comment: Do you really have JSON inside your JSON? That embedded `params` value looks like a JSON-encoded object to me so maybe you just need to fully decode the incoming data before it gets to your template.

Comment: It's wrapped in "", http://pastebin.com/pL2EJq7a

Comment: (1) JSON is a string format so it always be wrapped in quotes in JavaScript. (2) Have a look at `JSON.parse("{\u0022slider\u0022:\u00221\u0022}")` in your console.

Comment: Ok, should I stop trying to parse it directly in the underscore template? and focus in the marionette code? I can't find the way to get the item when marionette  renders the collection. I tried in the itemView initialize function but always get the collection not the child item.

Comment: Are you feeding your CompositeView a Backbone.Collection?

Comment: yes, and other items  are displaying correctly.

Comment: Yeah, whatever is getting that data from the outside world should be unpacking it, data processing like that should be at the edges of your application. I'm not sure where that would go with Marionette though.